# SendGrid Inbound Email Parse Body Raw NodeJS Lambda

Tags: json, parsing, sendgrid, boundary, busboy

I've been spending the last few days trying to find an easy way to parse what SendGrid is sending me. I'm trying to get it through AWS API Gateway then to a Lambda function to work with the data.

I tried with busboy but keep getting a boundary not found error even after setting the header type to "multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY"

Here's the request that I need to parse:

```
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dkim"

{@example-com.2wef01e50623.sfsmtp.com : pass}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

testing dispatch

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

inbouder@example.com
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spam_score"

0.737
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

Frank Violette <dude@example.com>
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sender_ip"

229.845.241.520

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="envelope"

{"to":["inboundparse@example"],"from":"dude@example.com"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="charsets"

{"to":"UTF-8","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SPF"

none
--xYzZY--
```

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!